# How to combine multiple nodes into one with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have this as my input:

```
<name>
  <n1>nisha</n1>
</name>
<name>
  <n1>aisha</n1>
</name>
<name>
  <n1>shankar</n1>
</name>
<surname>
iyer
</surname>
```

I want this as my output only for element with name tag:

```
<name>
<n1>nisha</n1>
<n1>aisha</n1>
<n1><shankar</n1>
</name>
```

Comment: As SMeyer has stated, please wrap your XML source document in a single root node.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your xml file needs a single root element, otherwise it cannot be processed, i.e.:

```
<names>
  <name>
     <n1>nisha</n1>
  </name>
  ...
</names>
```

A simple XSLT stylesheet that produces the required output is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/*"> <!-- Or match="/pathToNameElements" -->
    <name>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="name/n1" />
    </name>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name/n1">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="name[1]">
    <name>
      <xsl:copy-of select="/*/name/*"/>
    </name>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided text, corrected to be a well-formed XML document):

```
<people>
    <name>
        <n1>nisha</n1>
    </name>
    <name>
        <n1>aisha</n1>
    </name>
    <name>
        <n1>shankar</n1>
    </name>
    <surname>
iyer
    </surname>
</people>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<name>
   <n1>nisha</n1>
   <n1>aisha</n1>
   <n1>shankar</n1>
</name>
```

Comment: Note that this approach is quite unstable. For one, it will output all elements contained by <name>, not just <n1>. So if someone adds more elements, the transformation will break. It also breaks if there are <name> elements somewhere else in the document.

Comment: @SMeyer, One cannot guess whether or not if there were other children of `<name>`, the OP would or wouldn't want them also copied. So, your comment is just a speculation that reflects only one in many possibilities. **On the other hand**, when we are given a specific XML document, it is good to produce the shortest, most efficient and most straight-forward solution for *that* document. I have demonstrated short solutions for more generic and involved problems -- just look into my more than 5000 answers.

Comment: Of course you are right, without more detailed requirements, we can only speculate about the possible side-effects. Personally, I try to "catch" only the expected data, to minimize surprises. That might be too verbose for some, but has served me well in the past. In any case, both answers solve the problem as specified.